# Unable to see custom entity in Plugin Registration tool

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I registered a plugin assembly using the SDK Plugin registration tool. I am trying to add a step but cant see any of my custom entities in the Primary Entity field. Am I missing something here? It is a trial instance of CRM Online and I am logging into the default organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entities are only loaded once, and then cached by the Plugin registration tool.  Make sure you publish your changes in CRM, then completely shut down and restart the Plugin Registration tool.

Comment: The changes were already published, even reloading the organization did not work. But restarting the Plugin tool did! Thanks

Comment: That's when you mark this as the answer ;). I had the same issue a couple weeks ago.